# What is ADODB.Stream?

Tags: c#, adodb

What exactly is it, or was it, as is a interop, used for?

Here, this is the method where I use it:

```
    public void SaveAttachmentMime(String fileName, CDO.Message message)
    {
        ADODB.Stream stream = message.BodyPart.GetStream();

        String messageString = stream.ReadText(stream.Size);

        StreamWriter outputStream = new StreamWriter(fileName);

        outputStream.Write(messageString);
        outputStream.Flush();
        outputStream.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ADODB.Stream` object was used to read files and other streams. What it does is part of what the `StreamReader`, `StreamWriter`, `FileStream` and `Stream` does in the .NET framework.

For what the code in that method uses it for, in .NET you would use a `StreamReader` to read from a `Stream`.

Note that the code in the method only works properly if the stream contains non-Unicode data, as it uses the size in bytes to determine how many characters to read. With a Unicode encoding some characters may be encoded as several bytes, so the stream would run into the end of the stream before it could read the number of characters specified.

Comment: So it's use is merely for interoperability with a com?

Comment: @NoProblemBabe: Yes, you use it when a COM object returns or expects an `ADODB.Stream` object. For file and stream operations in .NET it's better to use the classes in the framework.

Comment: you said about the size of the stream, nice touch, it escaped me. Thanks for that. Do you have a suggestion how to by pass that?

Comment: @NoProblemBabe: You can read the stream to the end by specifying `adReadAll` or `-1` instead of the size.

Answer (score 1):

It is a COM object, which is used to represent a stream of data or text. The data can be binary. If I recall correctly, it implements the [IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface, which stores data in a [structured storage object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380369%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You can find the interop representation of the interface in [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.istream%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there any real need to use it nowadays, except dealing with interop?

Comment: Yes, that's the only scenario where it would be needed. As in your example where `CDO.Message`, which is a COM object, returns a `Stream` object from the `GetStream` method. As you indicated that code is pretty old. It's there because System.Web.Mail was a wrapper around CDO. Starting with version 2.0 of the framework, you would use the classes found in the System.Net.Mail namespace.